# $http.get in AngularJS fails

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

Hey I have problem with getting data from webpage to my own page.

I'm using Angularjs and try to take data from http://irys.wi.pb.edu.pl/bibWS/books I look my page in chrome and get: 
    `ReferenceError: $http is not defined`

My page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html ng-app> 
    <head> 
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>AngularJS</title>
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function LibraryController($scope) {
                var urlBase = 'http://irys.wi.pb.edu.pl/bibWS/books';
                $scope.books = $http.get(urlBase);
            } 
        </script>

        <div ng-controller="LibraryController">
            Title: <input type="text" ng-model="searchText" /><br />
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="book in books">
                <strong>{{book.title}}</strong> -
                <em>{{book.author_id}}</em></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to inject `$http` service into your controller

```
function LibraryController($scope, $http)
```

Comment: Okay that worked, I have data on page with data, but my page print just an empty list:

Comment: To access your object attribute do the following `{{book.title}} {{book.updated_at}}`

Comment: I'll paste new code now, with produce me always list with 4 empty elements.

Comment: One question every 90 minutes ;(

Comment: ok try that <ul ng-repeat="book in books">
  <li ng-repeat="(key, val) in book">
    {{key}}: {{val}}
  </li>
</ul>

Answer (score 3):

You should add `$http` to your controller:

```
function LibraryController($scope, $http)
...
```